# Redirect to new folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

To change the name of a directory, I have created a new duplicate directory, and wish to redirect calls for the old one to the new one. This is in the root directory’s htaccess.

```
Redirect 301 /as/oldarchive/ /as/newarchive/
```

Both addresses respond correctly when called from the browser address bar. But the redirect does not work.

(The directory has only one main page, an updating bulletin, reached by  htaccess DirectoryIndex statement. It uses no additional file call, and the file name is not seen by users.)

How should this redirect be written?

Note: The root directory is a first-level subdirectory of my main site. It is called directly with its own URL. Thus:

```
http://othersite.net/as/oldarchive/
```

is actually located here:

```
http://mainsite.net/othersite.net/as/oldarchive/
```

But placing a redirect in the main site's htaccess, reflecting this nesting, also doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect doesnt work"? Do you get a 404 error Or does it redirect you to a diffrent location?

Comment: Calling the old address, I still get that old address.

Comment: Do you have any other redirects in htaccess?

Comment: Not in that htaccess.

Comment: Try your redirect in "/as/oldarchive/.htaccess"

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this and many similar variations. Still no result.